# Having different color tones for DataGrid columns

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid and I want some columns to have different colors.

```
<DataGrid>
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />

      <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Weight">
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Weight}" />
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Weight}" />
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>

      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Created At" Binding="{Binding CreatedAt}" />
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I found posts about hard setting the background but I want something more smooth. It should fit in the mouse-over and selection actions and color accordingly but in a different color tone.

I want to make the difference visual for "default" columns, important columns and "readonly" columns.

[image: datagrid example]

Something like the above. Columns in different colors but still change colors a little bit if the row is selected for instance.
But how?

Comment: can you please explain a little about how do you want.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "more smooth"? And what are default/extend-values/readonly? Is it a property on the data object? If you can create a mockup picture of what you want, it'll be much easier for us to understand the problem.

Comment: What are "default" columns, "extended-values" columns? Does default mean ones you have defined, extended-values are auto-generated?

Comment: @GlenThomas: These columns don't differ in anything special. There are just columns more important than others to me.

Comment: What we need to know is how do we know which columns are default and which are extended values?

Comment: @GlenThomas: It does not matter. I define some column as more important and want them to be colored differently. They are not any more special program wise. I choose them.

Comment: @juergend Its pretty hard to understand what are you looking for ?? are you looking to change the color on mouse over that could be done simply by using triggers and setters but I bet you are looking for something more than that.can you elaborate the question please ?

Comment: @kyle: If I hard-code a specific color for a column, then it always has that color. But I want to set a color that still changes if for instance I select the row - then it should be colored differently in that row - like in my screenshot.

Comment: @juergend ok lets say if you select say "steve" then the row color should change depending on some condition ??

Comment: @kyle: Take the screenshot in my question. Claire is selected. The 3rd column is light-green. But for Claire it is not light-green all the time. It has a different color when selected. I want my table to act normal on all the actions I can take but with a different color tone for some columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution is to set proper `CellStyle` while auto-generating columns.
In the following `Xaml`, I've provided a style for the default state of `DataGridCell` that responds to mouse-hover, focus, selection and etc. Other states (e.g. read-only, extended, ... ) can be styled the same way with some minor changes in colors.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key='CellDefaultStyle' TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" >
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Arrow" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2 5 2 5" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Grid x:Name="Root" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="RightGridLine" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                   Width="1" Grid.Column="1" />
                        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="FocusVisual" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsHitTestVisible="false" 
                                   Opacity="0" Fill="Green" Stroke="DarkGreen" 
                                   StrokeThickness="1" Grid.Column="0" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundRectangle" Grid.Column="0" 
                                   Fill="LightSteelBlue" Opacity="0.25" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="SelectedRectangle" Opacity="0" 
                                   Fill="Blue" Grid.Column="0"  />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="HoverRectangle" 
                                   Fill="LightBlue" Opacity="0" Grid.Column="0"  />
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                                          Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property='Opacity' TargetName='FocusVisual' Value='0.8' />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" 
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="HoverRectangle" 
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" 
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="HoverRectangle" 
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger >
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="HoverRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0.5" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="HoverRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger >
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="HoverRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="HoverRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                                <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="False" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0.6" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridRow}, 
            Path=IsSelected, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key='CellReadOnlyStyle' TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" >
         <based on CellDefaultStyle with some minor change in colors ...>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

This is an example for a `DataGrid` with auto-column generation.

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" 
                  AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And this is how styles are chosen for different states while columns are generating:

```
    private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.IsReadOnly)
        {
            e.Column.CellStyle = (Style)Resources["CellReadOnlyStyle"];
        }
        else if (other states)
        {
            e.Column.CellStyle = (Style)Resources["CellOtherStyle"];
        }
        else
        {
            e.Column.CellStyle = (Style)Resources["CellDefaultStyle"];
        }
    }
```

**Update:**

If `AutoGeneratingColumns` is set to `False`, Since `DataGridTemplateColumn` and `DataGridBoundColumn` (e.g. `DataGridTextColumn`) are both have `CellStyle` property, you can set proper style for each column manually:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel.MyList}" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" CellStyle="{StaticResource CellDefaultStyle}" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Weight" 
                                    CellStyle="{StaticResource CellDefaultStyle}">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Weight}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Weight}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Created At" Binding="{Binding CreatedAt}" CellStyle="{StaticResource CellReadOnlyStyle}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

This screen shot, shows how the columns look like after the styling is done.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It works generally. But I have set `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` So this is no option for me.

Comment: If you define some columns and have AutoGenerateColumns="True", doesn't that mean you will have duplicate columns in the DataGrid?

Comment: @juergend: I don't think a solution for `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` is much different. please see my update.

Answer (score 3):

For Selected, ReadOnly and MouseOver it can looks like this

```
<Style x:Key='CustomCellStyle' TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" >
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger >
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
                    <Condition Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
            </MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger >
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
                    <Condition Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
            </MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger >
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                    <Condition Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
            </MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger >
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False" />
                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
                    <Condition Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
            </MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger >
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False" />
                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                    <Condition Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

I can't post comments to Bahman_Aries's post, so I post it here:
I didn't get why his solution is not working for you. If you have AutoGenerateColumns="False", it makes the solution easier, because you can manually set style for each columns.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Data 1" Binding="{Binding Data1}" IsReadOnly="True" CellStyle="{StaticResource CellReadOnlyStyle}"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Short and simple in your example

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window1_Load">
        <Window.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="clBl" Color="Blue" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="clred" Color="Red" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="clgreen" Color="Green" />
        </Window.Resources>
        <Grid>
            <DataGrid Name="grd" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" >
                        <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                <Setter Property="Background" 
                                    Value="{StaticResource clred}" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Weight">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Weight}" />
                            </DataTemplate>

                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Weight}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                <Setter Property="Background" 
                                    Value="{StaticResource clBl}" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Created At" Binding="{Binding CreatedAt}" >
                        <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                <Setter Property="Background" 
                                    Value="{StaticResource clgreen}" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

you can use HeaderStyle and FooterStyle also in same way

for mouse over and mouse leave make appropriate use of

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
         <Style.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                       Value="True">
                   <Setter Property="Background"
                           Value="Green" />
              </Trigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

or

```
 <DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                     Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="Pink" />
            </Trigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```